# Top level menu item "All" not available in Whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp, insider-preview

I can not see "All" top level menu item in Whatsapp. 
I have the latest version of Whatsapp installed: 2.16.308. on Windows developer preview.

If this menu item was removed intentionally, how can I add a contact who is using whatsapp and I have his phone number only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top lv menu removed. Add him to your phone as new contact, and he will appear in whats app

Comment: I have added a contact to People in my phone, but I can not see it in Whatsapp.

Comment: Are you sure that he/she have whats app